# Closed web parts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I have a Sharepoint site where click on edit item will open a new window. Unfortunately for one of the item ,it went to Web part maintanence page. I mistakenly closed that web part. Now I can't get any new window for any items. How to open the closed web part.

I am new to sharepoint and its a live system. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 8):

In order to view the Closed Web Parts, you just need to do:

- "Add Web Part" in any Web Part Zone
- Search for the "Closed Web Parts" category in the Web Part selection menu that appears on the Ribbon
- Your closed web parts should be right there

[image: Closed Web Parts]

Comment: Please mark as answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your site name is https://incorrecturl.omg.com/ABCDPage.aspx . Then please type the url appending "?contents=1" . 
Example would be : https://incorrecturl.omg.com/ABCDPage.aspx?contents=1 .This will show you all the webparts on ABCDPage.aspx . You can open the closed webpart on this page.

Comment: you cannot add the webpart on this page, you have to go through add webpart process.

Comment: How do you "open" the webpart? There is no option to open it.